# Check if email is within variable list of emails pulled from ADGroup

Tags: arrays, powershell, variables, foreach, contains

I'm trying to check if an email from an array pulled from a column in excel is within a list of emails from an AD group, and if so output that email with `Write-Host` to notify.

```
Clear-Host

$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Status.xlsx")
$WorkSheet = $WorkBook.Sheets.Item("PS1")
$members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity VIP | 
Get-ADUser -Properties emailaddress | Select emailaddress

$startRow = 2
$ColValues = @()
$count = $Worksheet.Cells.Item(65536, 7).End(-4162)
for ($startRow; $startRow -le $count.row; $startRow++) {
    $ColValues += $Worksheet.Cells.Item($startRow, 6).Value()
}

foreach ($email in $ColValues) {
    if ($members -contains $email) {
        Write-Host "$email is a VIP!" -ForegroundColor Red
    } else {}
}

Write-Host " "
Write-Host "Complete!" -ForegroundColor Green
```

If I run the above code it just goes straight to `Complete!` - but everything is listing properly for `$email`, `$ColValues`, and `$members`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found resolution by eliminating the need for the array and simplifying the script a bit. So basically I just moved the action into the for statement to do on each value as it gets it.

```
Clear-Host

$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Status.xlsx")
$WorkSheet = $WorkBook.Sheets.Item("PS1")
$members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity VIP | Get-ADUser -Properties emailaddress | Select emailaddress

$startRow = 2
$count = $Worksheet.Cells.Item(65536, 7).End(-4162)
for ($startRow; $startRow -le $count.row; $startRow++) {
{

    $emails = ($Worksheet.Cells.Item($startRow, 4).Value())
    $computerName = ($Worksheet.Cells.Item($startRow, 1).Value())

    if (($members -match $emails) -and ($emails -like "*")) {

        Write-Host "$emails is a VIP! " -ForegroundColor Green -NoNewline
        Write-Host " Computer Name: $computerName"

    } else {}   

}

Write-Host " "
Write-Host "Complete!" -ForegroundColor Green
```

The only downside to the was that I lose the ability to easily remove duplicated, and format it as a table. But given it's only 30-ish values being output, it worked perfectly for what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you trying to compare `$members` which is an **array of objects**(the one with property and value) and items from `$ColValues` which is an **array of values**.

You would want to fix that by changing `$members` variable this way:

```
$members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity VIP | 
Get-ADUser -Properties emailaddress | Select -ExpandProperty emailaddress
```

Or change `if` condition this way:

```
If ($members.emailaddress.Contains($email))
```

Comment: **Change `$members`**
It seems to `Write-Host` all the emails both in `$members` and the appropriate ones from `$ColValue`, creating doubles and triples and inaccurate output.

**Change `if`**
Seems to output the `Write-Host` for everything, but adds the variable email for the ones in the VIP ADGroup and just the string without the variable for all the others?

Comment: I've made a typo. it was supposed to be $members.emailaddress.contains($email)

Comment: _doesn't work_ is not very helpful. Try outputting some steps in between to see what you are comparing. What does `$members` contain; what does `$ColValues` contain etc. You can eliminate doubles by sorting both lists first with the `-Unique` parameter.

Comment: Adjust his `if` statement like he says and it writes out names, some repeating names idk why, and then will put ` is a VIP` on a new line occasionally. I tested both $email and $members and both are a proper list of emails.

Answer (score 0):

The `Get-ADGroupMember` function can return groups, computers and users. I think you should filter out anything that is not a user.

Also, by using `Select emailaddress` you will get an array of user **objects** as Kirill Pashkov already pointed out. You really only want to have an array of **strings**.

Try this for the `$members =` part:

```
$members   = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity VIP -Filter {objectClass -eq "user"} |
             Get-ADUser -Properties Emailaddress | 
             Select-Object -ExpandProperty Emailaddress | 
             Sort-Object -Unique
```

*The `Sort-Object -Unique` should not be necessary here, but just to make sure no duplicates are in there..*

I cannot check if your code actually gets the `$ColValues` from Excel in a correct manner. That is: if this results in an array of **strings** holding email addresses, but if so, uniquify that array too:

```
$ColValues = $ColValues | Sort-Object -Unique
```

**Final remark:**

You do not seem to close Excel after you have collected the values from it.
Best make a habit to close and release ComObjects when done with code like this:

```
$objExcel.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($WorkBook) | Out-Null
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($objExcel) | Out-Null
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback on closing out ComObjects. A little confusing what exactly that all is doing, so would appreciate some elaboration so I can better understand the parts of it.